# Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection. O/S Windows 7 Pro 64 bit

Tags: windows, tor-install, connection

I have updated Tor to 7.0.7, from 7.0.6. I get the error messages below:
'Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection.
Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed (done - 212.83.154.33:8443).'

O/S Windows 7 Pro 64 bit.

I also run IVPN at the same time as wanting to connect Tor. Tor does not run all the time and it connects to one website only. When finished working on that account, I disconnect it.
I have deleted Microsoft Security Essentials.

I have deleted and reinstalled Tor.

I have opened the command line using the link and get a response: '.' or 'start-tor-browser' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

The system clock is set to the correct time.
I deleted Tor 7.0.7 then downloaded and installed version 7.0.8 and this: Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed (done - 194.109.206.212:443)

Again, deleted Microsoft Security Essentials and Tor Browser, restarted computer, installed 7.0.8 and:

Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed (connection timeout - 193.23.244.244:443).

Stopping IVPN, deleting Tor, adding Tor to Windows firewall

Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed (done - 86.59.21.38:443).

Did this,
add the following code to the end of the file:
UseBridges 1
Bridge ip.ad.dr.ess:port abcd1234hash
Bridge ip.ad.dr.ess:port abcd1234hash
Bridge ip.ad.dr.ess:port abcd1234hash

from Andrew Lott♦ and Ali Torabi

Log 1:

```
27/10/2017 12:04:31 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/10/2017 12:04:31 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/10/2017 12:04:31 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/10/2017 12:04:31 PM.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27/10/2017 12:04:31 PM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
27/10/2017 12:04:32 PM.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
27/10/2017 12:05:44 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 10; recommendation warn; host ABF7FBF389C9A747938B639B20E80620B460B2A9 at 109.163.234.9:443) 
27/10/2017 12:05:44 PM.600 [WARN] 9 connections have failed: 
27/10/2017 12:05:44 PM.600 [WARN]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
27/10/2017 12:05:44 PM.600 [WARN]  2 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
```

Log 2:

```
27/10/2017 12:20:05 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/10/2017 12:20:05 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/10/2017 12:20:05 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/10/2017 12:20:05 PM.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27/10/2017 12:20:05 PM.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
27/10/2017 12:20:05 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
27/10/2017 12:21:04 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 39F096961ED2576975C866D450373A9913AFDC92 at 198.50.191.95:443) 
27/10/2017 12:21:04 PM.600 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
27/10/2017 12:21:04 PM.600 [WARN]  8 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
27/10/2017 12:21:04 PM.600 [WARN]  2 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
27/10/2017 12:21:06 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27/10/2017 12:21:06 PM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/10/2017 12:21:06 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27/10/2017 12:21:06 PM.900 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you're using Tor Browser Bundle - there's no Tor v7 nowdays as far as I'm concerned. Second - your connection looks like censored, so use meek pluggable transport and obfs4 - or try also obfs3. Post the resulting logs here, so we'll be able to fix your problem! Don't worry - it can be fixed!

Comment: Thanks for helping. Have used: obfs4, obfs3, meek-amazon, fte, meek-azure,

Comment: logs are too long by 36563 characters.

Comment: use https://pastebin.com/ for long log's paste - quite a handy service!

Comment: have used pastebin as you suggested, file title is 'torbroke'. Do I need to do anything else or can you access the file directly?

Comment: usually you paste thepastebin link here, so your file can be accessed by a click, so please paste it here

Comment: https://pastebin.com/u/robcnwll hopefully this is the link

Comment: yes, the link is correct, and can you please attach your torrc to your question? it's either a misconfiguration, or a locally-installed AV software, or one of the most deep censorship cases I've seen. We've solved such cases, but it was really hard - so don't worry and post the info, pls. Happy halloween!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/u/robcnwll  It's the 'untitled' file. I hope this is what you want? Browser/torbrowser/data/tor/torrc

Comment: yes it is. well - Tor Browser bundle has proven itself to me buggy-useless *again* in last 96 hours... You'll need to set up the expert bundle, I'll add the instructions to my answer tomorrow - have too much work today, going to sleep. dont worry, we'll mend it

Comment: has anyone got any answers, please?

Comment: @robert - use expert bundle, that looks to be your solution

Comment: I looked for the expert bundle but could not find it. Tor works fine on my other computers, so I will uninstall it on the one that's not behaving. I think it will be a reinstall of OS as I am seeing other software behaving badly. Thanks for your help

Comment: I will uninstall Tor. Thanks forthe help, Alexey Vesnin.

Comment: N.B. Do not try to use the expert bundle, you will not be anonymous. Alexey constantly gives users harmful information.

Comment: Try: https://tb-manual.torproject.org/en-US/circumvention.html

Comment: @canonizingironize he needs to use expert bundle for receiving a full error log at least: browser bundle gives out too few details if it gives them at all

Comment: No, they do not. Tor Browser provides the full error log which the user also provided: they need pluggable transports and possibly non-default bridges. *Not* the "Expert Bundle". Stop leading users down long and confusing paths off of the basis of your own incompetence.

Comment: I asked for help to get Tor working, Alexis Vesnin was the only person who answered and offered help and guidance. I think that if people just want to complain about someone offering to help, perhaps they could have offered suggestions. I have uninstalled Tor. I will reinstall Windows.